OpenVPN server installed on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 configuration
I would like to ask you some questions regarding the configuration of an openVPN server which I would like to set-up in a computer running and Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop version.

Is it possible to install an openVPN server in a computer running and Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop? I have seen many guides on how to do it on Ubuntu Server versions, but not Ubuntu Desktop versions.

If the previous question would be answered with a YES, then, would you mind guiding me on what might I be doing wrong?

I believe I have achieved to install the openVPN server on my ubuntu desktop. Nevertheless, it is only accessible on my LAN, and I cannot access it from outside my LAN. I believe the problem lies in the IP of my Ubuntu Desktop computer (192.168.XXX.XXX). I would like to be able to access it from anywhere with internet access, and be able to configure the VPN access from clients in different locations/networks.
I have registered a DNS with No-Ip, and I am communicating my public IP with it through my router, which has the option to send the public IP to No-ip. As an example, lets say that my hostname is "abcde.ddns.net" in No-ip, and that it successfully receives my public Ip from my router.
Since on my LAN, the admin and client accesses to openVPN are accessible through "https://192.168.XXX.XXX:943/admin/" and "https://192.168.XXX.XXX:943/login/", I have tried to forward port 943 also so that "public_ip:943/" would direct to 192.168.XXX.XXX/943". But I have not succeeded to achieve so...



Could someone please help me out with what I might have been doing wrong, in the event that installing OpenVPN server on a ubuntu desktop in a local network with the intention to setup a VPN server accessible from outside the LAN would be a doable thing to do.
Thank you very much, and please excuse me in advance if this question is not appropriate, I am no expert in informatics, and I am lacking some knowledge to understand what might I be doing wrong.

If you're able to access OpenVPN at 192.168.x.y:943, then the problem isn't in the Ubuntu end. It's this: "I have tried to forward port 943 also so that "public_ip:943/" would direct to 192.168.XXX.XXX/943". But I have not succeeded to achieve so" How to do that properly depends on your router, and really has nothing to do with Ubuntu, and isn't on-topic here. You can ask on [su] with more details about your router and what configuration you have tried with it.

(Also, for things like this, there's no difference between desktop and server.)

A good place to start is to do some research and studying before asking the question. It will save you a lot of time and the answer will make more sense. This link will give you some guidance. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
